# Spring add Comment Entity to Post entity on show page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I want to have a Post entity just like in stack overflow: you have a show page where you see what someone posted, but below you have field for comment. You don't have to be transfered to completely different page like /post/id/addComment.
I have Post entity:

```
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private Difficulty difficulty;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "post_category",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
    @Column(name = "categories")
    private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

    @Lob
    private Byte[] image;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "post",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    private String text = "";
    private String author = "";
    private String description = "";
}
```

And comment entity:

```
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumn(name="post_id")
    Post post;

    private String text = "";
}
```

I have html show page for post like that:

```
<p th:text="${post?.difficulty}"></p>
<p th:each="category : ${post?.categories}" th:text="${category?.text}"></p>
<p th:text="${post?.text}"></p>
<p th:text="${post?.author}"></p>
<p th:text="${post?.description}"></p>
<div>
    <p th:each="comment : ${post?.comments}" th:text="${comment?.text}"></p>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="../../static/images/tiger.jpg"
         th:src="@{'/post/' + ${post.id} + '/postimage'}"
         width="200" height="200">
</div>
<div>
    <form  th:object="${comment}" th:action="@{'/post/' + ${post.getId()} + '/comment'}"  method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
        <p>Description: <input type="text" th:field="*{text}"/></p>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

You see that above I list categories, text and other fields of Post. Below I added form just to add comment. It has hidden ID value generated automatically and text to fill in in input. When submitted I want it to be added to comment repository and to be assigned to Post. Only explanation I found is to redirect user to other page like "/addComment" and then proceed POST action, but it has no sense. Go to completely other page just to add comment? Anyone can help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can first redirect to /post/{id}/addComment and for the function controller you can return to /post/{id} shown below as below

```
@PostMapping("/post/{id}/addComment")
public String addComment(@PathVariable int id, @ModelAtribute Comment comment){
...
...//perform add comment

return "redirect:/post"+id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@RequestMapping("/cooment/{id}")
public String commentAdd(@pathVaribale("id")int id){

// comment.save()

return "redirect:/post"

}